# Does clean install reset everything, including SMC?

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, macos, firmware

**TL;DR**: Does a clean install reset *everything* (like SMC, for example)? If not, what else should I do to be sure the computer is completely reset, like it just came from the factory?

My macbook has been acting weirdly for the past few weeks, so I decided to give it clean install with Yosemite.

I think I messed up the SMC and resetting it does not help. I have a Bootcamp partition that I used to play games. My macbook pro would get very hot while gaming on Windows, so I installed [Lubbo's Fan Control](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lubbofancontrol/). That worked for a couple days, until I realized that while booted in OSX the fans were not working at all or working full speed. I tried resetting the SMC, but that didn't help. So I installed iStat Menus, and controlled my fans manually (yeah, a lazy solution). Now I have one fan controlling app on Windows and one on OSX, and neither work as expected (in iStat when I set it to 'default' the fans stop working).

Also, I have been installing a lot of things, and leftover files are all over the place.
So, now I'm getting rid of Bootcamp and clean installing Yosemite. How do I go about doing this properly and thoroughly? I'd like to make the computer fresh as it just came out of the factory. Should I do anything besides a clean install?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A fresh OS install won't reset the hardware, SMC or PRAM. It might be well worth checking both those are correctly reset before going so far as a wipe & install.

Reset the PRAM first - hold Cmd/Opt/P/R at the chimes & wait for the chimes to happen a second time.

SMC varies per machine, Mac Pro is sufficient to power off & leave the mains plug out for a minute. MacBooks are different - http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3964 covers all the variations.

Extract :

> **Resetting the System Management Controller (SMC)**
>
> **Resetting the SMC on Mac portables with a battery you can remove**
>
> 1. Shut down the computer.
> 2. Disconnect the MagSafe power adapter from the computer, if it's connected.
> 3. Remove the battery.
> 4. Press and hold the power button for 5 seconds.
> 5. Release the power button.
> 6. Reconnect the battery and MagSafe power adapter.
> 7. Press the power button to turn on the computer.
>
> **Resetting the SMC on portables with a battery you should not remove on your own**
>   **Note**: Portable computers that have a battery you should not remove on your own include MacBook Pro (Early 2009) and later, all models of MacBook Air, and MacBook (Late 2009).
>
> 1. Shut down the computer.
> 2. Plug in the MagSafe power adapter to a power source, connecting it to the Mac if its not already connected.
> 3. On the built-in keyboard, press the (left side) Shift-Control-Option keys and the power button at the same time.
> 4. Release all the keys and the power button at the same time.
> 5. Press the power button to turn on the computer.
>
> **Note**: The LED on the MagSafe power adapter may change states or temporarily turn off when you reset the SMC.
>
> **Resetting the SMC for Mac Pro, Intel-based iMac, Intel-based Mac mini, or Intel-based Xserve**
>
> 1. Shut down the computer.
> 2. Unplug the computer's power cord.
> 3. Wait fifteen seconds.
> 4. Attach the computer's power cord.
> 5. Wait five seconds, then press the power button to turn on the computer.

Comment: Thank you. I want to clean install anyway. Do I reset SMC and PRAM before reinstalling?

Comment: I'd reset both & see if it fixes things on its own - just might save you the trouble. If not, then you can always repeat before or after reinstall; it won't hurt anything. Run basic drive tests too - from Recovery or booted to OS. Disk Utility, repair permissions & verify [or repair] the disk.